# Can I assign an HTML string to the innerHTML property of a HTML DOM node?

Tags: javascript

I want to populate html elements from a given string and this seems to not update the html inside the `dynamic-content` div:

In `index.html`:

```
<div id='dynamic-content'>
</div>
```

In `index.js`:

```
var dynamicContentNode = document.getElementById('dynamic-content');
dynamicContentNode.innerHTML = '<div><p>oh hai</p></div>';
```

Did I just not test this well?

#### Edit: I was assigning to `innerHtml` NOT `innerHTML`

Comment: Can you expand on your usage of *fail*?

Comment: Looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Updating question now.  Basically, the innerHTML just doesn't seem set.

Comment: It's possible that your JavaScript is above your `<div>`.

Comment: That [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/upv23yab/); so, are you correctly linking to your `index.js` file? And have you read this question: "[Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById()` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)"

Comment: @Marty, I certainly loaded the javascript in the `<head>` tag accidentally, thanks.  Still not working yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works perfectly fine.

Assuming that you load the JS file in the header, and thus the DOM is not ready (the div doesn't exist at the time the JS executes), so you can wrap the whole thing in a `window.onload` callback or load the JS file at the very end of the HTML body.

See the difference between the two examples below reflecting what actually happens if you load the JS before and after the HTML.

---

### Non-working version:

```html
<script>var dynamicContentNode = document.getElementById('dynamic-content');
dynamicContentNode.innerHTML = '<div><p>oh hai</p></div>';</script>
<div id='dynamic-content'>
</div>
```

### Working version:

```html
<div id='dynamic-content'>
</div>
<script>var dynamicContentNode = document.getElementById('dynamic-content');
dynamicContentNode.innerHTML = '<div><p>oh hai</p></div>';</script>
```

### Non-working version made working using the onload callback:

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    var dynamicContentNode = document.getElementById('dynamic-content');
    dynamicContentNode.innerHTML = '<div><p>oh hai</p></div>';
  }
</script>
<div id='dynamic-content'>
</div>
```

Comment: After adding the non-working version, your working version doesn't work. I've never seen this code snippet feature before. Very cool. Not sure how I missed it.

Comment: Snippets are quite young here. What do you mean it doesn't work? The first one is supposed to fail, while the other two work fine.

Comment: None of them display anything in the results section when I try them.

Comment: Did you hit the run button?

Comment: Yes. I'm hitting the run button. The first version of your answer worked just fine. Your javascript is no longer within the js portion of the snippet. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I've never seen that happen with a snippet, even after a refresh? Anyway, that's what the problem with your code was, try implementing one of the solutions and see if it works for you.

Comment: Chrome console displays this error: "The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://stacksnippets.net/js' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header."

Comment: Did you try to load an actual file inside the snippet?

Comment: What do you mean? That's what they are for. Did you figure out what were you doing from with them?

Comment: Yes, question updated.  I was created a new property, `innerHtml`, by accident.  The method should've been, `innerHTML`